# Why would anybody want to use strlen instead of mb_strlen

Tags: php, utf-8

There is some legacy code, which I'm supposed to convert from `iso-8859-2` to `UTF-8`. One of the problems is a wide use of `strlen` function. I first thought that I will replace all of occurences of `strlen` to `mb_strlen`.

However, a colleague of mine said that this would be a mistake. I know the difference between the two functions - in case of accented characters in a string, `strlen` will return the number of bytes it really takes, while `mb_strlen` will return the number of characters.

And now, a colleague said that maybe, just maybe somewhere there is a situation where the return needs to be about the number of bytes in the string, but he couldn't give me any examples of such situation.

There are about 900 of `strlen` occurences in the entire code and it will take days to analyze every single occurence.

The question is - what are the potential situtations when a somebody would need the number of bytes instead of number of characters in a string?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.func-overload)  only thing you will have to change then is when you are trying to use strlen to get a byte count. Byte count is useful when you want to see how much space a string will consume when put in a container (like a db field or a fixed length file) this is also important if you are trying to report out a accurate Content-Length header

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few situations come to mind:

- Storing the string in a file or database
- Writing the string to a socket to send over the network
- Calling a legacy API or a COM method that requires the length in bytes

Comment: ok, thanks, but do you know what to look for in the code to detect this situations?

Comment: Generally one would need to consider how the result of strlen/mn_strlen is being used. Is it being passed to functions that require a number of characters, or functions that require a number of bytes? Beyond that it's hard to come up with a general rule, IMO

Comment: Normally edge cases like that should be covered by unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Also we should note that strlen is faster. In a simple test I did for a string with 20 chars and 1000000 repeats:

```
strlen    : 0.044954061508179
mb_strlen : 1.2507030963898
```

So if our string is ISO (and not utf-8) I think strlen is a better choice.